# Query correctly returns calculations but returns null when multiplied together in a sum

Tags: sql, db2, aggregate

I am trying to calculate the sum of two calculations multiplied together. Independently, the {Hours} and {Rate} calculations work just fine but when I multiply them together within a sum formula, they normally return a null. The exception is that they will return 0 if the rate is 0.

If anyone has an guidance, it would be appreciated. I would also love to know what I did wrong because I'm teaching myself this.

```
Select 
      SFLTX.BF2RDAT as {Date}, 
      SFLTX.BF2DEPT as {Dept},
      sum((SFLTX.BF2QTYG / HJOBDR.EDRUNS)) as {HOURS},
      (RESRE.ABLABR * ((RESRE.ABBRDP + RESRE.ABBDVP)/100)) as {RATE},
      sum((SFLTX.BF2QTYG / HJOBDR.EDRUNS) * (RESRE.ABLABR * ((RESRE.ABBRDP + RESRE.ABBDVP)/100))) as {ABS}
from SFLTX

join ERW.FCALPF on SFLTX.BF2RDAT = ERW.FCALPF.FDATE
join HJOBDR on SFLTX.BF2JOBN = HJOBDR.EDJOB# and SFLTX.BF2SEQN = HJOBDR.EDSEQ#
Join RESRE on SFLTX.BF2DEPT = RESRE.ABDEPT and SFLTX.BF2RESC = RESRE.ABRESC

where SFLTX.BF2RDAT > '1/1/2019' and (right(ERW.FCALPF.FYEAR,2) = ‘19’ and SFLTX.BF2CMODE = 'R')

group by SFLTX.BF2RDAT , SFLTX.BF2DEPT, (RESRE.ABLABR * ((RESRE.ABBRDP + RESRE.ABBDVP)/100))
```

I attached an image of the data output.

Comment: Using `sum()` without `group by` is broken SQL.  It is really hard to make a suggestion without sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0):

If any of the columns involved in any of the calculations contains NULL values, then the result of the calculation will likewise be NULL.  Ensure that either all columns are defined as NOT NULL, or, use a CASE statement to convert any NULL value to 0 or 0.00 (unless you are going to be dividing by that column).